# How to deploy ABP framework application to a Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, blazor-webassembly, abp, kestrel

I'm trying to deploy my ABP application to a Ubuntu 20.04 server on Amazon Lightsail. I'm using Abp with **Blazor UI**, **EFCore**, and **PostgreSQL** as DB, which runs perfectly fine on my local Windows machine with IIS Express.

I've followed [this Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to deploy my application to the **Ubuntu server**. Since ASP Net Core runtime is installed on the remote machine, I'm publishing all my projects as **framework-dependent**.

So far, I've managed to run Migrator on the server and seed the DB with Dataseeder. I also configured **Nginx** and **Kestrel** service to run my `HttpApi.Host` project on the server. (To clarify: `HttpApi.Host` runs perfectly fine, and I can get query results back by using the swagger interface.)
What I couldn't achieve is to run the Blazor UI. After copying published files to the server and configuring the Nginx, the root URL would redirect me straight to the swagger UI, bypassing the Blazor.

I tried to remove the `HttpApi.Host` from Nginx configurations and set the Blazor UI as the only URL ("/"), but as long as the kestrel service ran, the root URL automatically redirected to the `HttpApi.Host` (swagger interface). I then tried to stop and disable the kestrel service and hope to at least see the index.html, but that got me nothing but a 502 Bad Gateway error.

**Question:**
I basically want to run my Blazor UI and HttpApi.Host on the Ubuntu 20.04. What other steps are there to follow? I checked the [original abp docs](https://docs.abp.io/) but didn't find any resource about deploying on Linux.

Here's my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        root /home/ubuntu/myapp/Blazor;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

And here's my Kestrel configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=HttpApiHost .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myapp/MyAppApi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/myapp/MyAppApi/MyApp.HttpApi.Host.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=http-api-host-syslog
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no exact error message, I would suggest to configure your Linux environment gradually and make sure everything configured and installed probably:

- **ASP.NET Core:** A lot of resources to configure asp.net on Linux, and here is an example http://www.projectcodify.com/hosting-aspnet-core-on-linux-using-nginx , Then make sure you installed latest ASP.NET Core runtime
- **Blazor:** Deploy a simple Blazor web application and make sure it's working on server
- **DB:** do a simple listing page on your simple Blazor web app to make sure you configured the DB in the right way and it's working, I would prefer to start with external DB server or external managed PostgreSQL service , to focus only on configuring web server components in the beginning
- **ABP** once you stabilize the above web applications you will be ready to deploy your ABP application and discover issues related to ABP itself

Comment: I can confirm that both the DB and the API runs and works fine by running all my queries on the Swagger UI (I've updated my question accordingly). The problem is, no matter my Nginx configuration, I can't reach ABP Blazor UI from the root URL ("/").

Comment: So I think your issue in nginx.conf , check this one https://dev.to/helloitsm3/how-to-setup-blazor-app-with-nginx-and-docker-11le#chapter-3